# Calling Webservices in a loop won't execute the custom OnSuccess function

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery, web-services

I have a problem.
I am coding using VS2008.
I am calling webservices from my JavaScript Page.
An example

```
Services.ChangeDropDownLists.GetNowPlayingMoviesByLocationSVC(
    blah, 
    OnSuccessMoviesByRegion, 
    OnError, 
    OnTimeOut
);
```

after execution, it goes to the function `OnSuccessMoviesByRegion`.

But if I put the Services in a loop (a simple for loop)

```
Services.ChangeDropDownLists.GetNowPlayingMoviesByLocationSVC(
    blah[i], 
    OnSuccessMoviesByRegion, 
    OnError, 
    OnTimeOut
);
```

`OnSucessMoviesByRegion` function won't execute (but the service call executes n times successfully
But I must have the function cos I am returning value through it.

What am I missing?
Is that the typical behaviour?
Any alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Naveen, I'm answering your [follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/256634/calling-webservices-in-a-loop-wont-execute-the-custom-onsuccess-function#256658) here. I can think of two options:

1. Try to make a single call packaging your data (sending the whole blah array and handle it on the server).
2. Use a counter variable which you decrement in the "OnSucces" client handler each time and stop if this counter variable reaches 0.

Answer (score 1):

I guess there is some kind of **concurrency problem**. Probably you fire the next request before the last one finished.

I think you'll have to rewrite the loop. Try to move that code, calling only the first request and then using the "OnSuccess" function to call the next one each time.